# How do I rerender FlatList after 3 different onPress actions?

Tags: react-native

The idea is to have a toggle switch that switches from **To Watch** and **Watched** bookings, i.e. movies where the objects containing the bookings have three buttons - one that sets the bookings as watched, one that sets the bookings as to be watched and one that completely removes them. This is the code I have:

```
const WatchList = () => {

  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState('To watch');
  const [filteredBookings, setFilteredBookings] = useState(bookings);

  const bookingsRef = collection(db, "booking"); // imamo ref ka bazi

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    getBookings();
  },[])

  const getUser = async () => {
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
    setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
  }

  const getBookings = async () =>{
    const q = query(bookingsRef, where("users","array-contains",auth.currentUser.uid));
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const a = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {            
        a.push(doc.data());
      });
      setBookings(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }

  const toggleSwitch = () =>{
    if(!watched){
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == true;
      }))
      setText('Watched');
    } else {
      setText('To watch');
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == false;
      }))
    }
    setWatched(previousState => !previousState);
  }

  const updateBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: true
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const updateBooking1 = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: false
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const deleteBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id));
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const resultOfFiltering = bookings
    setFilteredBookings(resultOfFiltering)
  }, [bookings])

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
        <Switch 
          value = {watched}
        />
      </View>
  
  <FlatList
    data = {filteredBookings}

    renderItem  = {({item}) => (
      <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.data().movie}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data().day} - {item.data().showtime}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        {item.data().watched == true ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.delete} onPress = {() => {setWatched(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/watched.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setToWatch(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/towatch.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>)}

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {deleteBooking(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/remove.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
      </View>
  )
}

export default WatchList
```

How would I go about rerendering the FlatList based on which button is pressed? So far if I delete the booking the FlatList rerenders itself without the deleted booking, but I'm not sure how to use the useEffect hooks to get it to rerender the list with the added or removed bookings based on if they're watched or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t really understood what your approach is. But from what I understand is, that you want to somehow rerender the Flatlist data, if its state have changed right?

If so try following:

const [rerenderToggle, setRerenderToggle] = useState(true);

Set rerenderToggle as extraData={rerenderToggle} in your FlatList.

After every change you made to your FlatList, change the value of rerenderToggle (by doing setRerenderToggle(!rerenderToggle) ).

By changing extraData (it doesn‘t matter what is inside of it) FlatList will basically being told to rerender due to data change.

I hope this‘ll help you to solve your problem.

Excuse the formatting, I‘m on mobile.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have a toggle that switches between To Watch and Watched. When I press on the button to change the state of the booking in the To Watch list, I want it to rerender without that movie since it switched over to the Watched list. So when I would switch the toggle from To Watch to Watched, I would now see the updated movie there. And the same for reverse. 

I got it to rerender the FlatList when I delete a booking, but I'm not sure how to do this. Could you please help me?